# Why is my AES encryption (CBC) giving me the wrong encrypted output in Arduino?

Tags: android, encryption, arduino, aes

As part of a project, I am supposed to demonstrate 128-bit AES encryption in Arduino. Unfortunately, there is not much information on how to implement this in Arduino compared to for example, Android, which gives me my desired encrypted output.

Here is the sample code (https://gist.github.com/EC12-Code/73b19a98c759c777e303a75e94d6ed21) which I have referred to to implement AES, unfortunately when I compare the encrypted output to online tools, the encrypted output for Arduino is different but for Android it is the same. Somehow, the Arduino code still manages to give the desired decrypted output however, which confuses me. Is it a format issue? I am a newbie at this and I have no idea what is causing this difference, shouldn't the same key and IV used give the same encrypted output anyways?

Code on Arduino's side (with ref to the link above):

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <hwcrypto/aes.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <base64.h>

static inline int32_t _getCycleCount(void) {
  int32_t ccount;
  __asm__ __volatile__("rsr %0,ccount":"=a" (ccount));
  return ccount;
}

char plaintext[16384];
char encrypted[16384];

int encodetest()
{
//uint8_t key[32];
//uint8_t iv[16];
unsigned char iv[16] = {0x57, 0x6E, 0x5A, 0x72, 0x34, 0x75, 0x37, 0x78, 0x21, 0x7A, 0x25, 0x43, 0x2A, 0x46, 0x2D, 0x4A};
unsigned char key[32] ={0x66 ,0x54 ,0x6A ,0x57 ,0x6E ,0x5A ,0x72 ,0x34 ,0x75 ,0x37 ,0x78 ,0x21 ,0x41 ,0x25 ,0x44 ,0x2A ,0x47 ,0x2D ,0x4A ,0x61 ,0x4E ,0x64 ,0x52 ,0x67 ,0x55 ,0x6B ,0x58 ,0x70 ,0x32 ,0x73 ,0x35 ,0x76};

  strcpy( plaintext, "Hello" );
  Serial.printf( "\n================================Encode================================\nIV HEX:" );

  for(int d = 0; d < sizeof(iv); d++) {
  Serial.printf( "%02x", iv[d] );
  }
  Serial.printf( "\nKey HEX:" );
  for(int f = 0; f < sizeof(key); f++) {
  Serial.printf( "%02x", key[f] );
  }
  
  Serial.printf("\nWill Encode \n%s",plaintext);
  //Just FYI - you must be encrypting/decrypting data that is in BLOCKSIZE chunks!!!

  esp_aes_context ctx;
  esp_aes_init( &ctx );
  esp_aes_setkey( &ctx, key, 256 );
  int32_t start = _getCycleCount();
  esp_aes_crypt_cbc( &ctx, ESP_AES_ENCRYPT, sizeof(plaintext), iv, (uint8_t*)plaintext, (uint8_t*)encrypted );
  int32_t end = _getCycleCount();
  float enctime = (end-start)/240.0;
  Serial.printf( "Encryption time: %.2fus  (%f MB/s)\n", enctime, (sizeof(plaintext)*1.0)/enctime );

  //See encrypted payload, and wipe out plaintext.
  memset( plaintext, 0, sizeof( plaintext ) );
  int i;
   Serial.printf( "Hex" );
  for( i = 0; i < 128; i++ )
  {    
  if  (i % 8 == 0) {Serial.printf( " " );};
    Serial.printf( "%02x", encrypted[i] );
  }
  Serial.printf( "\n================================Decode================================ \n" );
  //Must reset IV. Otherwise first block will fail
unsigned char iva[16] = {0x57, 0x6E, 0x5A, 0x72, 0x34, 0x75, 0x37, 0x78, 0x21, 0x7A, 0x25, 0x43, 0x2A, 0x46, 0x2D, 0x4A};

for(int c = 0; c < sizeof(iva); c++) {
 Serial.printf( "%02x ", iva[c] );
}

memset( iv, 0, sizeof( iv ) );  

  //Use the ESP32 to decrypt the CBC block.
  esp_aes_crypt_cbc( &ctx, ESP_AES_DECRYPT, sizeof(encrypted), iva, (uint8_t*)encrypted, (uint8_t*)plaintext );

 Serial.printf( "\nHuman Readable\n" );
 
  //Verify output
  for( i = 0; i < sizeof( plaintext ); i++ )
  {
   // printf( "%c",  (plaintext[i]>31)?plaintext[i]:' ' );  
   Serial.printf( "%c", plaintext[i]);
  }
  Serial.printf( "\n" );

  esp_aes_free( &ctx );
}

void setup() {
  // put your setup code here, to run once:
   Serial.begin(115200);
   Serial.println("Execute Begin");

int a = encodetest();
}
```

Code on Android's side:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    EditText inputText, inputPassword;
    TextView outputText;
    Button encBtn, decBtn;
    String outputString;
    String AES = "AES";
    private static final String SECRET_KEY = "fTjWnZr4u7x!A%D*G-JaNdRgUkXp2s5v";
    private static final String SALT = "ssshhhhhhhhhhh!!!!";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        inputText = findViewById(R.id.inputText);
        inputPassword = findViewById(R.id.password);

        outputText =findViewById(R.id.outputText);
        encBtn = findViewById(R.id.encBtn);
        decBtn = findViewById(R.id.decBtn);

        encBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                try {
                    outputString = encrypt(inputText.getText().toString());
                    outputText.setText(outputString);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    public static String encrypt(String strToEncrypt) {
        try {
            byte[] iv = {0x57, 0x6E, 0x5A, 0x72, 0x34, 0x75, 0x37, 0x78, 0x21, 0x7A, 0x25, 0x43, 0x2A, 0x46, 0x2D, 0x4A};
            IvParameterSpec ivspec = new IvParameterSpec(iv);

            //SecretKeyFactory factory = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("PBKDF2WithHmacSHA1");
            //KeySpec spec = new PBEKeySpec(SECRET_KEY.toCharArray(), SALT.getBytes(), 65536, 256);
            //SecretKey tmp = factory.generateSecret(spec);
            //SecretKeySpec secretKey = new SecretKeySpec(tmp.getEncoded(), "AES");
            byte[] key = SECRET_KEY.getBytes("UTF-8");
            SecretKeySpec secretKey = new SecretKeySpec(key, "AES");

            Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
            cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, secretKey, ivspec);
            byte[] encVal = cipher.doFinal(strToEncrypt.getBytes());
            String encryptedValue = Base64.encodeToString(encVal, Base64.DEFAULT);
            return encryptedValue;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Error while encrypting: " + e.toString());
        }
        return null;
    }

}
```

Plaintext: Hello

Encrypted output from Arduino:

7c6e13cc7e943313 ee111a1c90387c04 ac1fa7a7c491d53e be6eea1feaf01815 d7733389f23dd8f4 ed6dae3e78f5388e 1eda7bbbaf3bad5f 1b5b0d01281805d4 2c38139fcda0a05b 7eded259247e105b 16b228aacefc89ee 9dd2db2392537168 63adf145feb2b33a 287c5a5623212a0d c8760ed78ffc6508 a1e95d6235895ef5

Encrypted output from Android, which is the same as the one generated from online tools:

[image: Android encrypted output]

[image]

Any help would be much appreciated in helping me understanding why the Arduino output is different, thanks!

Comment: You encrypt plaintexts of different length: In the C code a 16384 bytes long plaintext starting with `Hello` and following 0x00 values (from the ciphertext 128 bytes are output), in the other two cases the 5 bytes large string `Hello`. Note also that Android and the website pad with PKCS#7, while `esp_aes_crypt_cbc()` (presumably, s. [here](https://github.com/espressif/arduino-esp32/issues/1518#issuecomment-399681732)) does not.

Comment: If you want to compare runtimes, then create two identical library functions that you **call from** your application code and compare that using the same values, identifiers and such. When debugging these things you want the code to look as alike as warranted by the language / runtime conventions. At least you'd use the same encoding for the input & output (you're currently comparing hex output with base 64 output... why?).

Comment: A different note is that most online tools suck for debugging this kind of thing. If possible try and find some official test vectors or something. Online tools usually do all kinds of undocumented processing, such as the PKCS#7 compatible padding in this tool.